# What is the difference between finding the hazard function by using an NHPP and fitting a Weibull curve to the data for a repairable system?

Tags: survival, reliability, poisson-process, hazard, weibull-distribution

When modelling a repairable system, one should use a non-homogeneous Poisson Process (NHPP). E.g., the moment the hazard function I use in the NHPP is a Weibull function. However, I have difficulty explaining why I can't just fit the same Weibull function via regression to the same data (something like age vs the percentage of failure incidents at that age) to get the shape and scale governing the hazard rate.

- If the parameters are the same, then the NHPP is a more complicated
  approach.
- If the parameters are different, the NHPP shape and scale won't
  generate a best-fit line on the data described.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How flexible is your fit of the NHPP? A standard Weibull fit would implicitly assume that the regression coefficient values are constant in time. Might your fitting of the NHPP allow for different coefficient values at different times after `time = 0`? Providing some more details, perhaps a comparison of fits done both ways, might help clarify the issues at hand.